# platformBrowserDynamic lazy loading different module

Tags: angular, ionic2, lazy-loading

I have an application created in ionic which is much big in size and without lazy loaded pages. it contains over 30 pages and over 100 components. The problem is generated main.js is very big in size even after production build it is taking 5-6 seconds to load. Adding lazy loading to every page will cause lots of rework. so what i wanted to do is create different module named splashModule which contains html and js for complex animation. and i want to bootstrap it via platformBrowserDynamic and then after some seconds i want to bootstrap my original app. but doing so includes code of both module in main.js file. I want to lazy load second module per need basis. so can you please guide me how to do that?

Application is in ionic v3 framework.

Answer (score 0):

A way that comes to mind is to build the whole app as a lazy module, and load it after a delay. E.g. `index.html` is your "light" angular page, which after fancy loading, has `setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate('home')`, and app is, in your main module, the home for the "real" app. Did you try something like that?

Comment: This approach seems complicated to me. can you provide any link where this is implemented? As im reading through tutorial there is option to navigate to component , not whole module.

Comment: No, but this sounds like what your question was about: lazy load the app.

Comment: Sure, it definitely is interesting.

Comment: Can you tell me is this a good practice or not?

1) comment main.js script include in index.html file
2) make static splash in index.html file and put js also there
3) after sometimeout load main.js file
4) from angular app call global function ( which is from js of splash screen ) to remove splash screen and script from dom

Comment: Well if you want that, you don't need all the timeout stuff. Just create a splash screen within `<app-selector>` tags, when the app is loaded, it's going to remove the splash screen automatically and render the app.

Comment: yes you are right. but i am wondering maybe it might affect splash screen performance. because it contains some complex animations.

Comment: Well, the splash-screen performance is either behaving, or not. If it is a requirement that it runs for X seconds, then yes, by all means, do a timeout version of loading. You can do it in your main.ts or whatever. If it is not an explicit requirement, don't worry. It'll work on good devices, it'll be jumpy on old phones. Timeout or no timeout.

At least that's what I think.